# Perl or sed: Regex replace with group capture

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I cannot seem to make `sed` do a regex replace with group capture in this example:

- Input: "DONE project 1"
- Desired putput: "project 1 DONE"

What I tried with `sed`:

```
$ echo "DONE project 1" | sed -E 's/^DONE(.*)$/$1 DONE/g'
$1 DONE  # fail! no group capture in `sed`?
```

Is there a way to do this in `Perl`?

Actually this is part of an AppleScript used by DEVONthink[^1], and I realized that `sed` was not able to do regex search/replace with group capture.

[^1]: DEVONthink's search/replace script with AppleScript usage

```
set transformedName to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of itemName & " | sed -E 's/" & sourcePattern & "/" & destPattern & "/g'"
set name of selectedItem to transformedName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can easily do this, use  `\1`, `$1` is the Perl backreference syntax:

```
sed -E 's/^DONE(.*)/\1 DONE/g'
```

`.*` matches all the line up to the end, so you do not have to use `$` in the LHS.

Comment: Even though it doesn't *need* the `$`, I like to put it in anyways as a reminder to myself in six months that I intended to slurp the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl version is very close to the `sed` version because Perl stole some of `sed`'s features:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^DONE(.*)/\1 DONE/'
```

The `-p` effectively wraps `while(<>) { ...; print }` around your argument to `-e`.

Note that the `/g` flag doesn't make much sense here. You're going to match the first `DONE` and everything after it. There's no second match to make.